# Making hyperlink to cell in filtered table persistent

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

Is it possible to create a hyperlink to a cell in a filtered table on another sheet and have it such that no matter how the table is filtered (i.e. A-Z or Z-A) the link will always point to the cell with the correct data even though it's cell reference has changed?

Comment: To make a reference to some cell static and positional-independent you may add dollar signs to its row and column address parts. The most simple way to do it is to place the cursor into the cell address (`A|1` or `R1|C1`) and press F4 once.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. When I set it up initially with a link to, for example cell A3 on sheet 2, it works but then if I sort the table from Z-A instead of A-Z the hyperlink still goes to cell A3. I want it to link to wherever the original cell linked to is.

Comment: Yes that's it - destination cell moves. I want it so that if I add a new row to the table it doesn't break any of the hyperlinks so I'm not sure a named range would work as the range would change if I add a new row, surely?

Comment: Sorry... I have tested - reference to name is non-workable too. It seems the hyperlink is attached to address, and the value is attached to address. While sorting the values changes their attach points whereas hyperlink - no.